# How to save scrapy crawl data to 2 related tables in postgresql django?

Tags: postgresql, django-models, sqlalchemy, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am using Sqlalchemy to store crawled data from spinder into Postgresql Django database. However I have a problem with the Image field.

Because Image and Product are in 2 different tables and I don't know what to do with Piplines.

My code works fine without the Image field.

**My codes are as follows:**

**Django**:

**models.py**

```py
# models.py - django
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_image")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images/", default="/no_image.jpg")
```

**Scrapy:**

**items.py**

```py
# items.py - scrapy
import scrapy

class ShoppProduct(scrapy.Item):
    slug = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    image = scrapy.Field()
```

**piplines.py**

```py
# piplines.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from .models import Shop_Product, create_items_table, db_connect

class ShoppSpinderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):       
        engine = db_connect()
        create_items_table(engine)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.session = Session()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):  #
    item_exists = self.session.query(Shop_Product).filter_by(slug=item['slug']).first()

    if item_exists:
        item_exists.title = item['title']
        print('SP {} updated.'.format(item['title']))
    else:
        new_item = Shop_Product(**item)
        self.session.add(new_item)
        print('Item {} created.'.format(item['title']))
    return item

def close_spider(self, spider):
    try:
        self.session.commit()
    except:
        self.session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        self.session.close()
```

models.py - Sqlalchemy

```py
# models.py - Sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, Boolean, DateTime, ForeignKey, Table, event
# ...
from . import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

# ...

class Shop_Product(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    slug = Column("slug", String, unique=True)
    title = Column("title", String)
    
class Shop_ProductImage(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "shop_productimage"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column("product_id", Integer) # Id of product
    image = Column("image", String)
```

What do I have to do with the relationship in the models.py file - Sqlalchemy?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The initial solution to the above question includes:

- Add relationship in models.py
- Modify the file pippelines.py as below:

**models.py - Sqlalchemy**

```py
# models.py - Sqlalchemy
class Shop_Product(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    slug = Column("slug", String, unique=True)
    title = Column("title", String)
    
class Shop_ProductImage(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "shop_productimage"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column("product_id", Integer) # Id of product
    image = Column("image", String)
    # relationship
    products = relationship('Shop_Product', backref='image1') # add new. image1 will be used in pipelines.py
```

**pipelines.py**

```py
class ShoppSpinderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):

        engine = db_connect()
        create_items_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        pro = Shop_Product()
        img = Shop_ProductImage()
        pro.slug = item['slug']
        pro.title = item['title']
        pro.regular_price = item['regular_price']
        pro.discount_price = item['discount_price']
        img.image = item['image']

        exist_img = session.query(Shop_ProductImage).filter_by(image=img.image).first()
        if exist_img is not None:
            pro.image1 = exist_img
        else:
            pro.image1.append(img)

        try:
            session.add(pro)
            session.commit()

        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise

        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

This answer is incomplete because it hasn't checked for duplicate product urls. You will get an error if you run it a second time if the product already exists in the database.

I will update the answer when a more complete solution is available.

I asked another question about this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376528/how-to-update-price-only-when-product-already-exists-in-pipelines-scrapy](http://I%20asked%20another%20question%20about%20this:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376528/how-to-update-price-only-when-product-already-exists-in-pipelines-scrapy)